# How to send a message using Viber Bot

Tags: node.js, viber

I can't send a message using Viber Bot.

I tried this option:

```
const TextMessage = require('viber-bot').Message.Text

viber_bot.sendMessage(req.body.viber_user_id, new TextMessage(req.body.message))
```

As a result, the **error**:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Invalid arguments passed to sendMessage. 'optionalReceiver' and 'chatId' are Missing.
```

Tried it like this:

```
viber_bot.sendMessage({
    "receiver": "<my_id>",
    "type": "text",
    "text": "Hello world!"
}
```

With this approach, there is no error, but there is no message either, it does not come!

**P.S.**
Please note that the rest of the bot works fine.
Messages are accepted and I can send a reply.

Answer (score 0):

`sendMessage()` needs `UserProfile` instead of just `viber_user_id`

Following should work:

```js
const receiver = "to viber user";
const sampleUserProfile = { id: receiver };
const text = "sample message";
const sampleTrackingData = { value: "sent 1 message" };
const sampleKeyboard = { button: { bgColor: "#FFFFFF" } };
const sampleChatId = "sample chatId";
const sampleMinApiVersion = 2;
const sampleMessage = new TextMessage(text, sampleKeyboard, null, null, null, sampleMinApiVersion);

viber_bot.sendMessage(sampleUserProfile, sampleMessage, sampleTrackingData, sampleChatId);
```

Also please note, that there are 2 implementations which can cause issues for you, depending on what you actually use:

1. ```
   ViberClient.prototype.sendMessage = function (optionalReceiver, messageType, messageData, optionalTrackingData, optionalKeyboard, optionalChatId, optionalMinApiVersion)
   ```
2. ```
   ViberBot.prototype.sendMessage = function (optionalUserProfile, messages, optionalTrackingData, optionalChatId)
   ```